# Plotting multiple line graphs in matplotlib using plt.plot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, linechart

I'm using the following code.

```
%matplotlib notebook
plt.style.use('seaborn-bright')

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6), facecolor='w', edgecolor='blue')
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)

plt.title('Clubs of Severn Valley Petanque League - performance in years 2014-2019',color='purple',size=14.5,y=1.09)

ax.set_ylabel('Year', color='indigo',size=10)
ax.set_ylabel('Points won', color='darkblue',  fontdict={'fontsize': 12, 'fontweight': 'medium'})

years=[2014,2015, 2016,2017,2018, 2019]
plt.xticks(np.arange(5), (years))
plt.margins(x=0.006,y=0.009)
ax.get_xaxis().tick_bottom()
ax.get_yaxis().tick_left()

ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.FuncFormatter('{:.0f}'.format))
ax.grid(True, 'major', 'y', ls='--', lw=.6, c='darkgray', alpha=.5)

ax.tick_params(axis='y', which='both', labelsize=10,bottom=False, top=False, labelbottom=True,
               left=False, right=False, labelleft=True)
plt.legend(loc=2)

# Now I call each column( one for each team) one by one like so :

plt.plot(final.Points_Kinver.values, marker='o', label='Kinver Con Club')
plt.plot(final.Points_Nomads.values, marker='o', label='Nomads')
plt.plot(final.Points_TopPub.values, marker='o', label='Top Pub')
plt.plot(final.Points_Plough.values, marker='o', label='Plough')
plt.plot(final.Points_AlveleyRoyals.values,  '-o', c='violet', label='Alveley Royals')
plt.plot(final.Points_Footloose.values, marker='o', c='yellow', label='Footloose')
plt.plot(final.Points_Gaters.values,  '-o', c='orange', label="Gaters 'A'")
plt.plot(final.Points_AlveleyOaks.values,  '-o',c='darkgreen',  label='Alveley Oaks') 


plt.show()
```

It works. Here is my chart [image].

However, I wish I could write plt.plot as one line, and this does not work.

```
plt.plot(final.columns.values, marker='o')
```

This causes an error.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-277-f48c020019fc> in <module>()
     44 #mychart=final.plot( marker='o',ax=ax)
     45 
---> 46 plt.plot(final.columns.values, marker='o')
     47 
     48 #plt.plot(final.Points_Kinver.values, marker='o', label='Kinver Con Club')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in plot(*args, **kwargs)
   3356                       mplDeprecation)
   3357     try:
-> 3358         ret = ax.plot(*args, **kwargs)
   3359     finally:
   3360         ax._hold = washold

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in inner(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1853                         "the Matplotlib list!)" % (label_namer, func.__name__),
   1854                         RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
-> 1855             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1856 
   1857         inner.__doc__ = _add_data_doc(inner.__doc__,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in plot(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1525         kwargs = cbook.normalize_kwargs(kwargs, _alias_map)
   1526 
-> 1527         for line in self._get_lines(*args, **kwargs):
   1528             self.add_line(line)
   1529             lines.append(line)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in _grab_next_args(self, *args, **kwargs)
    404                 this += args[0],
    405                 args = args[1:]
--> 406             for seg in self._plot_args(this, kwargs):
    407                 yield seg
    408 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in _plot_args(self, tup, kwargs)
    381             x, y = index_of(tup[-1])
    382 
--> 383         x, y = self._xy_from_xy(x, y)
    384 
    385         if self.command == 'plot':

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in _xy_from_xy(self, x, y)
    214         if self.axes.xaxis is not None and self.axes.yaxis is not None:
    215             bx = self.axes.xaxis.update_units(x)
--> 216             by = self.axes.yaxis.update_units(y)
    217 
    218             if self.command != 'plot':

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py in update_units(self, data)
   1467         neednew = self.converter != converter
   1468         self.converter = converter
-> 1469         default = self.converter.default_units(data, self)
   1470         if default is not None and self.units is None:
   1471             self.set_units(default)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\category.py in default_units(data, axis)
    113         # default_units->axis_info->convert
    114         if axis.units is None:
--> 115             axis.set_units(UnitData(data))
    116         else:
    117             axis.units.update(data)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\category.py in __init__(self, data)
    180         self._counter = itertools.count(start=0)
    181         if data is not None:
--> 182             self.update(data)
    183 
    184     def update(self, data):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\category.py in update(self, data)
    199         for val in OrderedDict.fromkeys(data):
    200             if not isinstance(val, VALID_TYPES):
--> 201                 raise TypeError("{val!r} is not a string".format(val=val))
    202             if val not in self._mapping:
    203                 self._mapping[val] = next(self._counter)

TypeError: ('Points_Kinver',) is not a string
```

I have also tried

```
ax=final.plot( marker='o')

for line, name in zip(ax.lines, final.columns):

    y = line.get_ydata()[-1]
    ax.annotate(name, xy=(1,y), xytext=(6,0), color=line.get_color(), 
                xycoords = ax.get_yaxis_transform(), textcoords="offset points",
                size=8, va="center")
```

It works.  However, it creates 2 figures. 
Figure 1:  the empty customized figure with all of my carefully coded formatting, more specifically, ticks and gridlines ( ax.grid...) and the chart title. 
Figure 2: it contains the lines with labels, but all customized formatting and the title are lost.

Can you explain what is happening here?

My next step is labelling the end of each line  instead of the legend.
so I thought I need my plt.plot code in a single line..

As you can see, I'm not very experienced in matplotlib/python. I am trying to practice by creating a visualisation for my local petanque association. thank you for your help with my little project.

Comment: 1. No loss of honor if you plot separately the lines 2. If you really want, use `final.plot(ax)` first and THEN apply your customizations.

Comment: I am afraid it does not work. I am getting 2 separate charts, the customized empty one (figure 1) without the lines, and figure 2 with the lines only.

Comment: Try `final.plot(kind='line', marker='o', ax=ax)`